# Help with Related Posts Function

Tags: query, mysql, wpdb

I'm trying to write a function that will grab all related posts according to the term of a taxonomy. I'm having trouble though trying to query multiple terms.

The way I am doing it right now is using whatever the first term is to query related posts. Any idea how to check if it is multiples?

```
function related_posts($related_type, $related_tax) {

    global $wpdb, $post;

    // Get The Related Term
    $terms = array();
    foreach(wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $related_tax) as $term){
        $terms[] = $term->slug;
    };

    // Grab The First Term From The Array
    $related_term = array_shift(array_values($terms));

    // Query The Related Posts
    $related_posts = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "
        SELECT * 
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = '$related_type' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = '$related_tax'
        AND $wpdb->terms.slug = '$related_term'
        AND $wpdb->posts.ID <> $post->ID
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
        "
    );

    if($related_posts) {
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($related_posts as $post):setup_postdata($post);
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
            endforeach;
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'No related posts found';
    }

}
```

I would like something like: if this term OR this term OR this term THEN display all related posts.

I had previously used $wpdb->terms.slug IN ('$terms') but this would only show related posts with that exact match.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the "posts2posts" plugin by scribu?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wordpress's tax_query arg when fetching posts to achieve what you're trying to do, this is also easily extendable with more than one taxonomy.

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => $YOUR_POST_TYPE,
    'posts_per_page' => -1 // get all
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR'
    )
);

$query['tax_query'][] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'YOUR_TAXONOMY',
    'terms' => $ARRAY_WITH_TERMS,
    'field' => 'ID',
    'operator' => 'IN'

$query['tax_query'][] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_2',
    'terms' => $ARRAY_WITH_TERMS_2,
    'field' => 'ID',
    'operator' => 'IN'

$posts = query_posts( $query );
```

Might this be what you're looking for?